# Same block of code in a SELECT TYPE in Fortran

Tags: fortran

I’m wondering if there is an elegant way to avoid repeating block of code that apply to different types in a `SELECT TYPE construct`. Consider for example:

```
select type (var)
   type is (t1_t)
     codeA (many lines of code)
   type is (t2_t)
     codeA (same lines)
   ...
   type is (tn_t)
     codeB
   class default
     codeC
end select
```

Comment: Put codeA in a subroutine.

Comment: You may find other questions here relating to 'templating' concepts in Fortran.  `include` being one suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unlike the `select case` construct, where you can group multiple tests in the same case satement, there is no such facility in the `select type` construct.

The reason is: within the block of each type-guard statement, the selector (variable or expression you're matching) will have the same type as named in the type-guard statement, and won't be polymorphic there. This is how you can have dynamic type resolution in Fortran, that is statically typed.

```
select type (var)
  type is (t1_t)
    ! Here, type of var is t1_t, and you can call
    ! procedures that use type(t1_t) as arguments with var
  type is (t2_t)
    ! Here, type of var is t2_t, and procedures expecting
    ! type(t1_t) as arguments won't work with var
  ...
end select
```

Therefore, compiler can't allow you to group many types in the same type-guard, because it would't know which dynamic type to apply on the selector.

As a side note, unlike switch satement in c-derived languages, select constructs in Fortran do not *fall through*, i.e., after a match in Fortran, the corresponding block is executed and the control exits the construct.

As @cup said, you can convert whatever you have in common on the various branches in a subroutine in order to avoid repetition. But be aware that if you need to pass `var` to the routine, you must declare it as polymorphic dummy.

Comment: Rodrigo: your explanations are very clear. Thanks! (and Indeed, this is the  'select case' I had in mind). Cup: yes, using a subroutine... may be the simplest solution and that's what I finally did. Francescalus: I hadn't thought of that solution. I will try it, even though I usually use "include" statements sparingly (generally, I find the resulting code  less "readable"). Thanks all for your help.

Answer (score 0):

As francescalus pointed out in the comments, the typical way to repeat the same lines of code is to use an include file. This  is a traditional technique which used to be widely used for common blocks and is also used for poor-man's templating.

included.f90:

```
codeA (many lines of code)
```

main.f90:

```
select type (var)
   type is (t1_t)
     include "included.f90"
   type is (t2_t)
     include "included.f90"
   ...

end select
```

If you use the C preprocessor, you can use the preprocesor's `#include` as well.

Answer (score 0):

There is the overloaded operator type of construct that the 'type is' suggests. That needs to be in a module as a subroutine or function. I mostly use functions, so if one is mixing with C, then subroutines may be easier than a function trying to return a vector.

It will still be the same exact code, just operating on a complex, float, double, or variety of integer but depths... so there is no explicit 'type of' as the right version is selected based upon the arguement types.